# What is the best extension available for integrating Aramex module with Magento 1.9.2?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, aramex

**Aramex API Integration with Magento**

I have integrated  [Aramex Shipping and Tracking Extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/18134/s/aramex-shipping-and-tracking-extension-7606) with magento 1.9.2.3, and I updated aramex global settings in back end.

But I'm facing some errors.

1. Customer can't see Shipping rate calculation option in front end.
2. Admin Can't Prepare Aramex Shipment from back end. Showing some error

Anybody can help me to solve this issue? Or suggest any other extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have contacted Aramex Technical Support Team . And they send me latest aramex extension for Magento.Now its working Perfectly

Comment: How did you solve the issue, Aramex: ERR01 - ClientInfo - Invalid username or password,,,, and what is the details i need to enter here https://snag.gy/Upudaw.jpg

Comment: First you have to register in Aramex and create an customer account using your email and put those information's in customer email and password section

Comment: After i update exact username and password still getting the same error... How can i solve the issue?

Comment: My be your account not activated . Please co ordinate with aramex team to activate your account. And check with them you have to use test account or your own active account for testing purpose . If test account collect test account details from them.

Answer (score 1):

From my real experience `Magento 1.9.2.4`. they've a plugin on "connect" that you mentioned but it's not updated and you're so discouraged to use. **read the reviews on it**

The best way is to send the account manager an email asking for the plugin and he'll redirect you to a technical team then they'll send the module zipped. But take care of the time they take to respond .. so you've to follow the issue well.
then test the plugin and don't close the channel with them till you try a real shipment to ensure that every thing is going well.
good luck

Comment: I have contacted with Aramex technical support team then they send me a module in zip format . I installed it with fresh magento 1.9.2 and updated aramex Global Settings in back end. but from front end and backed facing an error **Aramex: ERR01 - ClientInfo - Invalid username or password**. And i informed the support team then they are saying to add SOAP library

Comment: @fresher actually you need to reach to your account manager as there's no direct connect with the technical team. If I understood right this team is outsourced so you can't connect directly. must be through the account manager. so if you're a developer ask the client to put you in contact.

Answer (score 0):

Please first check Aramex shipping extension is working with default magento or not.If you have installed any other module then please disable.

Also, there is one paid extension is available 
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/marketplace-aramex-shipping.html